# Can DBT transformations be run in batches?

Tags: dbt

By default, a DBT transformation on a table tries to ingest and process the entire table in one query.  If it's a large table, this can be a very resource-intensive process, and if anything goes wrong at any point, the entire transformation fails.  Is there any way to alleviate this by making the transformation run in smaller batches?

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that there is only one source table, and no `GROUP BY`, aggregates, or window functions being processed.

(I'm aware that I could get the SQL generated by DBT and run it in a loop with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. What I'm looking for is a way to get DBT to do this for me.)

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t use an incremental model in your use case?

Comment: @AdamKipnis Because incremental only works on new data that's been added since the last sync; I'm looking at a very large table in the initial sync.

Comment: That's what I wanted to confirm. The straight up answer is no - you can't do this natively in DBT. You could hack a solution like 1) create multiple models that are dedicated to a partition of the data that writes to separate tables, then create another model to put everything together; or 2) Write an incremental model that takes in `--vars` params specifying partitions to run and executing the job multiple times. Both kind of ugly. Usually in a situation like this, you try to minimize your full refreshes, use a scaled up instance (if using Snowflake), and rely more on incremental runs.

Comment: @AdamKipnis "The straight up answer is no - you can't do this natively in DBT."  Let me guess: you can't do this *because* there's no good way to set up a general solution if you're using models that do have stuff like aggregates or window functions?

Comment: DBT doesn't care if your data is aggregated. It's basically just a SQL scripting platform, after all. I think it's really just that DBT hasn't implemented a feature like this yet (kind of like how I'd wish they would implement a true SCD2 materialization that updates valid until dates of previous record versions like they do with snapshots). I didn't originally think of going down the custom materialization route that Josh D posted in his answer. Ultimately, that would be the ideal solution, but also the more complicated approach.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you're asking for is an experimental materialization called insert_by_period: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-labs-experimental-features/tree/main/insert_by_period

Essentially dbt will do the looping over your incremental model, inserting in batches for you.  The version linked above is written for Redshift but I've been at companies who have adapted it for Snowflake, etc.

Another approach is to do the batching on the orchestration side by adding parameterization and passing vars, like Adam Kipnis has suggested in the comment.

Comment: This is very interesting. I hadn't seen this before (probably because I mostly work with Snowflake). Doesn't work with updated records though...